# What's the meaning of "Web exploded" mean in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am a new java learner and choose idea as my ide.
Now I am confused of the meaning of "Web exploded" as the image shows.

[image: exploded]

Comment: It means that instead of deploying a war file, it will deploy a directory with the exact same tructure as a war file, but just not zipped into a war archive.

Answer (score 36):

Exploded = **unpacked**. Normally web apps are deployed in war/ear archives (essentially `zip`). Using exploded deployment [allows updating](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html) application without redeploying or restarting the server. The server doesn't need to unpack the web application when it's deployed, it just uses the files that are present in the directory.

This way you can test your changes much faster when developing and debugging, then you can build war/ear artifact and deploy it on the production server.